# Finding the decision boundary between two gaussians

Tags: bayesian, classification, normal-distribution

Assume we are trying to classify between 2 classes, each has a Gaussian conditional probability, with different means but same variance, i.e. $X | y=0 \sim N(\mu_0, \Sigma); X | y=1 \sim N(\mu_1, \Sigma)$.

Our decision rule would be $1 \iff P(y = 1 | X) > P(y=0|X)$ (and vice versa for 0).

Using Bayes rule we can invert the conditional probabilities, and get: $\iff \frac{P(X|y=1)P(y=1)}{P(X)} > \frac{P(X|y=0)P(y=0)}{P(X)}$.

We can next eliminate the denominator.

Now, if $P(y=1) = P(y=0)$ we could eliminate that as well, and the decision rule would be simplified to $P(X|y=1) > P(X|y=0)$, which basically is which $\mu$ is $X$ closer to. Now intuitively this translates to $1 \iff X > c = \frac{\mu_0 +\mu_1}{2}$.

I have 2 questions:

1. Can we prove this intuition mathematically?
2. What happens if $P(y=1) \neq P(y=0)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes you can. For example, 
   $$
   \mathbb{P}\left(X=x|y=1\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X=x|y=0\right)
   $$
   happens exactly when $x$ is between the means, which can be calculated directly from the definition. Essentially, you are finding the decision boundary for this image, [image: description],

but it's even simpler because you are assuming that the standard deviations are equal. You'd need to show with a simple equation that the probability (area under the curve) on the right is equal to the area on the left if the boundary is in the middle.

2. I'm not willing to do the math here, but you have to slightly alter the equation above to find what happens to the boundary. I can tell it doesn't change linearly, because, for example, if you believe the left bubble to be twice as likely as the right bubble, you're looking for a boundary so that the area under what's left of the left bubble is half that of what's right of the boundary under the right bubble.

Answer (score 2):

For 1D, i.e. $\Sigma = \sigma^2$ :

1. $P(X|y=1) > P(X|y=0) \iff \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma^2}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_0)^2}{\sigma^2}} \iff 
   \\e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma^2}} > e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_0)^2}{\sigma^2}} \iff \ln(...) > \ln(...) \iff -\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma^2} > -\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_0)^2}{\sigma^2} \iff \\ (x-\mu_1)^2 < (x-\mu_0)^2 \iff x^2 -2x\mu_1 + \mu_1^2 < x^2 -2z\mu_0 + \mu_0^2 \iff \\ \mu_1^2 - \mu_0^2 < 2(\mu_1-\mu_0)x \iff (\mu_1 + \mu_0)/2 < x$
   $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$
2. $P(X|y=1)p > P(X|y=0)(1-p) \iff \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma^2}}p > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_0)^2}{\sigma^2}}(1-p) \iff \\e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma^2}}p > e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_0)^2}{\sigma^2}}(1-p) \iff \ln(...) > \ln(...) \iff \\ -\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma^2} + \ln(p) > -\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu_0)^2}{\sigma^2} + \ln(1-p) \iff ... \iff \\x > \frac{\mu_1 + \mu_0}{2} + \frac{\sigma^2}{\mu_1-\mu_0} \ln(\frac{1-p}{p})$
   $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

For 2D and more, it can be shown (though the derivation is too much for me to MathJax right now) that (given identical co-variance matrix $\Sigma$ for both distributions):

1. $\iff 2(\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1 - \mu_0))^T X > \mu_1^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu_1 - \mu_0^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu_0$
2. $\iff 2(\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1 - \mu_0))^T X > \mu_1^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu_1 - \mu_0^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu_0 + 2\ln(\frac{1-p}{p})$

You can also check [here](http://www.svcl.ucsd.edu/courses/ece271A/handouts/GC.pdf) for the general case where the co-variance matrices aren't equal.

Comment: Very good, but you need to specify what $\sigma^2$ is and how it relates to the $\Sigma$ that you use in your question. Note that your results will still apply if the observation is a multidimensional Gaussian random variable _provided that_ $\Sigma = \sigma^2I$ _where_ $I$ _is the_ $n\times n$ _identity matrix but not if_ $\Sigma$ _has nonzero off-diagonal elements._

Comment: @DilipSarwate added some more clarifications

Comment: While one can glibly write stuff for two (or more) dimensions, the decision boundary is _not_ linear as in the case of one variable when $\Sigma$ (and hence $\Sigma^{-1}$) is a non-diagonal matrix.

Comment: The results I added for multiple dimensions are for whatever covariance matrix, given that both Gaussians share it.

Comment: I just came across this answer. Thank you! I was wondering whether we can write the multivariate versions of the decision boundary as a function of $X$ so that, for example, I can plot it for certain choices of means and covariances.