# Decision boundary between two Gaussians of unequal variance

Tags: probability, classification, gaussian-mixture-distribution

This question is concerning a similar problem as mentioned in this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/453396/finding-the-decision-boundary-between-two-gaussians). The only difference is that in my case the variances are **unequal**.

To recap, consider a two class scenario. At the decision boundary, the posterior probability of classifying a data point into two classes will be equal i.e. $p(y=1|x) = p(y=2|x)$

Posterior definition

$p(y=1|x) = \frac{p(x|y=1) * P(y=1)}{p(x)}$

$p(y=2|x) = \frac{p(x|y=2) * P(y=2)}{p(x)}$

where likelihoods are Gaussian i.e.

$p(x|y=1) = \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_1, \sigma_1)$

$p(x|y=2) = \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_2, \sigma_2)$

So at the decision boundary, $p(y=1|x^*) = p(y=2|x^*)$ where $x^*$ is the threshold

$
\begin{align}
&p(y=1|x^*) = p(y=2|x^*) \\
&\Longrightarrow\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1^2}}\exp(-\frac{(x^* - \mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}) * P(y=1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_2^2}}\exp(-\frac{(x^* - \mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2})* P(y=2)\\
\end{align}
$

Taking log on both sides,

$
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow & \small-\frac{(x^* - \mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2} -\log\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1 + \log P(y=1)= -\frac{(x^* - \mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2} -\log\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2 + \log P(y=2)\\
\end{align}
$

To get the threshold, we would solve for $x^*$ in the above equation. But since the variances are unequal this will remain a quadratic equation and hence it is possible to get complex values for $x^*$.

If this is the case, then what does it mean to have a complex threshold?

##### Further context:

I'm using a 2 component Gaussian mixture model and planning to find the threshold to create a mask as specified in the paper snippet below. As such, I was expecting the threshold to be real in order to create the mask. Hence my confusion.

[image]

Comment: It isn't possible to get complex values.  The boundary is circular.

Comment: So the root of the quadratic equation i.e. $x^*$ is guaranteed to be real?

Comment: Yes.  Geometry makes this obvious: the boundary occurs where the ratio of the distances to the two centers is a constant.  Such loci are circles.  (When that ratio is $1,$ the locus is the perpendicular bisector of the centers, which is a generalized circle of infinite radius; when the ratio is $0,$ the locus reduces to a point: a circle of zero radius.)

Comment: When the variances differ and you are in two dimensions, the boundary is elliptical: see the first two figures in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81952/919.  It is possible for the set of solutions to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The solution x* will be two real values.</strike>

This sort of decision boundary is typical in mixture models, for instance $\sigma_1^2 = 1$ is a "typical" scenario, and $\sigma_2^2 = 100$ is an "outlier" scenario.

The low variance, highly peeked distribution is selected around its mean; elsewhere above and below this region attributed to the low variance distribution, the diffuse high variance distribution is selected.

West & Harrison discuss models involving "typical" and "outlier" observation variance $V$, in their notation $V_\text{typical}=1$ and $V_\text{outlier} = 100$.

- West, Mike, and Jeff Harrison. *Bayesian forecasting and dynamic models*. Springer Science & Business Media, 2006.

Comment: The assertion on which this post is based -- there will be two real values -- is not correct in all cases.

Comment: @whuber - please provide a counter example relevant to the OP's case, "variances are unequal", $\sigma_2^2 > \sigma_1^2 > 0$.

Comment: See my [first comment to another answer in this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/533544/decision-boundary-between-two-gaussians-of-unequal-variance/533638?noredirect=1#comment980752_533708).

Comment: In a mixture of "typical" and "outlier" observations, often $P(\text{typical}) \gg P(\text{outlier})$.  In the opposite scenario (corresponding to the point made by @whuber above), when a relatively more precise distribution is a "small enough" component of a mixture, the posterior probability of the precise distribution may be always less than ("below") the posterior probability density of the more diffuse distribution.

Answer (score 0):

##### Verification attempt via quadratic discriminant:

To check the nature of roots of this equation, we could check the discriminant and confirm if it's greater than or equal to 0 for real solutions and less than 0 for complex ones.

Consider the previous equation
$$  
\begin{align}  
\small-\frac{(x^* - \mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2} -\log\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1 + \log P(y=1)= -\frac{(x^* - \mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2} -\log\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2 + \log P(y=2)\\  
\end{align}  
$$Rearranging a bit we get,$$  
\begin{align}  
\small\frac{(x^* - \mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2} -\frac{(x^* - \mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}+\log\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1 -\log\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2    + \log P(y=2) -\log P(y=1)=0\\  
\end{align}  
$$Group the log terms,$$  
\begin{align}  
\rightarrow \small\frac{(x^* - \mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2} -\frac{(x^* - \mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2} + \log \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2} + \log \frac{P(y=2)}{P(y=1)} = 0\\  
\rightarrow \small\frac{(x^* - \mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2} -\frac{(x^* - \mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2} + \log \frac{\sigma_1P(y=2)}{\sigma_2P(y=1)} = 0  
\end{align}  
$$Let's now only consider the first two terms and for convenience set  $\log \frac{\sigma_1P(y=2)}{\sigma_2P(y=1)} = k$ a constant.
Expanding the squares we get,$$  
\begin{align}  
\frac{2(\sigma_2^2 - \sigma_1^2 )x^{*^2} -4(\sigma_2^2\mu_1 - \sigma_1^2\mu_2)x^* + 2(\sigma_2^2\mu_1^2 - \sigma_1^2\mu_2^2)}{4\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2} +k=0\\  
\frac{0.5(\sigma_2^2 - \sigma_1^2 )x^{*^2} -(\sigma_2^2\mu_1 - \sigma_1^2\mu_2)x^* + 0.5(\sigma_2^2\mu_1^2 - \sigma_1^2\mu_2^2)}{\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2} +k=0\\  
0.5(\sigma_2^2 - \sigma_1^2 )x^{*^2} -(\sigma_2^2\mu_1 - \sigma_1^2\mu_2)x^* + 0.5(\sigma_2^2\mu_1^2 - \sigma_1^2\mu_2^2) + k\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2=0
\end{align}  
$$
For a quadratic equation of the form $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, the discriminant ($\Delta$) $= b^2 - 4ac$

From (6) we calculate the individual terms,
$$  
\begin{align}  
b^2 =\left(-(\sigma_2^2\mu_1 - \sigma_1^2\mu_2)\right) ^2= \left(\sigma_1^2\mu_2 - \sigma_2^2\mu_1\right) ^2\\  
4ac =4 * 0.5(\sigma_2^2 - \sigma_1^2 )* \left(0.5*(\sigma_2^2\mu_1^2 - \sigma_1^2\mu_2^2)+ k\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2 \right)\\  
= 4 * 0.5(\sigma_2^2 - \sigma_1^2 )*0.5* \left(\sigma_2^2\mu_1^2 - \sigma_1^2\mu_2^2+ 2k\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2 \right)\\
= (\sigma_2^2 - \sigma_1^2 ) \left(\sigma_2^2\mu_1^2 - \sigma_1^2\mu_2^2+ 2k\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2 \right)\\
= (\sigma_1^2 - \sigma_2^2 ) \left(\sigma_1^2\mu_2^2-\sigma_2^2\mu_1^2 - 2k\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2 \right)\\
\end{align}  
$$Calculate discriminant
$$  
\begin{align}  
b^2 - 4ac = \left(\sigma_1^2\mu_2 - \sigma_2^2\mu_1\right) ^2 - (\sigma_1^2 - \sigma_2^2 ) \left(\sigma_1^2\mu_2^2-\sigma_2^2\mu_1^2 - 2k\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2 \right)\\  
=   \left(\sigma_1^2\mu_2 - \sigma_2^2\mu_1\right) ^2 - \left(\sigma_1^4\mu_2^2 - \sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\mu_1^2-2k\sigma_1^4\sigma_2^2 - \sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\mu_2^2 + \sigma_2^4\mu_1^2 + 2k\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^4\right)\\
=   \left(\sigma_1^4\mu_2^2 -2\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\mu_1\mu_2 +\sigma_2^4\mu_1^2\right) - \left(\sigma_1^4\mu_2^2 - \sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\mu_1^2-2k\sigma_1^4\sigma_2^2 - \sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\mu_2^2 + \sigma_2^4\mu_1^2 + 2k\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^4\right)\\
= \sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\left(\mu_1^2 +\mu_2^2 - 2\mu_1\mu_2  + 2k(\sigma_1^2 - \sigma_2^2)\right)\\ 
= \sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\left( \left(\mu_1 - \mu_2\right)^2  + 2k(\sigma_1^2 - \sigma_2^2)\right)\\   
\end{align}  
$$

So the discriminant $\Delta =\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\left(\left(\mu_1-\mu_2\right)^2 + 2\log \frac{\sigma_1P(y=2)}{\sigma_2P(y=1)}(\sigma_1^2 - \sigma_2^2)\right)$.

<s>It can be seen that since the discriminant is strictly non-negative, it's not possible for complex solutions to arise.</s>

Edit: This is **incorrect**. As pointed out by @whuber in the comments, setting $P(y=2)$ to a low value would cause $\Delta$ to be negative.

Comment: (1) You really don't have to work this hard.  At the outset, change to the variable $y = (x-\mu_1)/\sigma_1$ and 90% of your algebra will be unnecessary. (2) Everything comes down to the unproven assertion that $\Delta \gt 0.$ Unfortunately, that is generally false, because by making $P(y=2)$ sufficiently small, $\Delta$ can be made negative.

Comment: My bad. You're right. But if the threshold ($x^*$) can't be complex why is it possible for $\Delta$ to be negative? Shouldn't the condition $\Delta >=0$ hold for real thresholds? Either I'm missing something obvious here or my calculation is incorrect.

Comment: There's no such thing as a complex threshold: one therefore looks only for real solutions.  It is possible for there to be no real solutions, in which case there is no threshold: you would conclude there is just one class.

Comment: So it is possible for roots to be complex! But the implication is that there is no decision surface.

Comment: But didn't you reply Yes when I asked whether the roots of the quadratic equation are guaranteed to be real? (In the comments section of the question). Just want to be clear so I have a proper understanding.

Comment: The *only* roots one looks for are real.  Complex roots, whether they might exist or not, are not relevant.  I apologize for misleading you.

Comment: Not at all. Thanks a lot for your patience and for clarifying my doubt.